# R: Indexing a matrix by a vector with individual indices for each row or column

Tags: r

I have a matrix and a vector:

```
mat <- matrix(data = c(1,2,3, 5,2,4, 8,2,2), ncol = 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    8
[2,]    2    1    2
[3,]    3    4    2

vec <- c(1,3,2)
```

What I want: the 1st, 3rd and 2nd element (as specified in vec) of each rows, i.e. `c(1, 2, 4)`. How ca I do this other than by a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cbind` to create a row/column index and then extract the elements based on the location

```
mat[cbind(seq_len(nrow(mat)), vec)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R trick

```
t(mat)[(seq(ncol(mat))-1)*ncol(mat)+vec]
```